# ASP.NET server side control not fired in a JQuery popup

Tags: jquery, asp.net

i've an ASPX page with 2 jquery popup. Each of this popup has a pairs of server side buttons.
The problem is that these button will not fire if i press.
I know it is an issue with jQuery popup .. how can i solve this ?

EDIT: Follow code

```
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolder1" runat="server">
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {


            var dlgSuggestSol = $('div#dlgSuggestSolution').dialog({ autoOpen: false, modal:true, width:640, height:480 })
            $('#btnOpenSuggestSolution').click(function () { $('div#dlgSuggestSolution').dialog('open'); });
            var dlgWaitSol = $('div#dlgWaitingSolution').dialog({ autoOpen: false, modal: true, width: 640, height: 480 })
            $('#btnReadSolutionAwaiting').click(function () { $('div#dlgWaitingSolution').dialog('open'); });

            })

    </script>
```

...
...

```
<div id="dlgSuggestSolution">
    <h3>Proponi la tua soluzione</h3>
    <br />
    <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="txtNewSolution" TextMode="MultiLine" Width="480px" Height="300px"></asp:TextBox>
    <br />
    <asp:Button runat="server" ID="btnSaveSolution" Text="Salva soluzione" />
    <asp:Button runat="server" id="aBUtton" Text="jjkkj" />
        <asp:Label runat="server" ID="lblMsg">
        </asp:Label>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you please add the code of the popup and the buttons

Comment: Can you post some code? Can you elaborate more about jQuery Popup issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set `UseSubmitBehavior="false"` on buttons in popup. The reason is that popup shown out of the form and usual submitting won't pass target control id to the server. But with `UseSubmitBehavior="false"` button uses the ASP.NET postback mechanism (`__doPostBack` function actually)

Answer (score 0):

Is your div "dlgSuggestSolution" visible on page load?

I am assuming that since its a popup, the initial behavior of div will be `visible=false.`
If that is the case, your code will not work.

Instead of `visible=false`, use `display=none` under style.